# How to implode data in array with commas from database column where has value = 1 in foreach statement?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to create array from database column that only has value = 1 and skip value = 0. I have column day from Monday to Sunday that they are column. They may have value 1 or 0.

```
$dr = $this->mdokter->daftarDokter($bag);
foreach($dr as $d) {
          if($d['monday'] == 1) {
            $data[$no]['jadwal'] = "Monday";
          }
          if($d['tuesday'] == 1) {
            $data[$no]['jadwal'] .= "Tuesday";
          }
          if($d['wednesday'] == 1) {
            $data[$no]['jadwal'] .= "Wednesday";
          }
          if($d['thursday'] == 1) {
            $data[$no]['jadwal'] .= "Thursday";
          }
          if($d['friday'] == 1) {
            $data[$no]['jadwal'] .= "Friday";
          }
          if($d['saturday'] == 1) {
            $data[$no]['jadwal'] .= "Saturday";
          }
          if($d['sunday'] == 1) {
            $data[$no]['jadwal'] .= "Sunday";
          }
}
```

the code above only produce data witout commas and not array.
How I can create array from them that only has value = 1. I want to collect the array in `$jadwal` variable. For example $jadwal = array("Monday", "Thursday", "Saturday");

Comment: change the lines like `$data[$no]['jadwal'] = "Monday";` to `$data[$no]['jadwal'][] = "Monday";` (without the dot in front of the equal sign for all lines)

Comment: another way would be: use `array_filter` to remove all entries theire values are not 1 and after that use `array_keys` another way would be to use `array_reduce`. so many ways to achieve this. just select one and try it. After that: show us your code and ask a specific question if you have any problems.

Comment: @JoshuaK wow, thanks for your help. SOLVED. by adding [] in the last variable.

Comment: I wont write an answer for that. Just delete the question :) There is not   a superordinated interest in this question ;)

Comment: But I want to archive this question to be my own note. And maybe it help others.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this in different ways:

First: save it directly into an array: To achieve this you have to change `$data[$no]['jadwal'] = "Monday";` to `$data[$no]['jadwal'][] = "Monday";`. Now the field jadwal inside the $data array is an array itself and not a string. The brackets are a short hand for array_push. So Monday will be pushed to the jadwal array. Repeat this change to the other lines as well and you get an array of days at the end, where the database field equals `1`.

Another way: Create an array of all names of the week and filter this array with the result from the database:

```
$jadwal = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', ...];
$jadwal = array_filter($jadwal, function($day) use($d) { return $d[$day]==1; });
```

these two lines replace all of your lines above.

If you need the first letter in upper case just use `ucfirst`